# Need help to evaluaet this limit.

Tags: limits

How do I evaluate this limit? Can someone explain to me?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{-n}+3}{2^{-n}+1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\l}[2]{\lim_{{#1}\to {#2}}}$$
Use,
$$\l{n}{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=0$$

> $$\l{n}{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2^n}+3}{\frac{1}{2^n}+1}=\frac{0+3}{0+1}=3$$

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm so dumb. I didn't realized that.

Comment: It happens with me too

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{-n} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

this is $$\frac{\frac{1}{2^n}+3}{\frac{1}{2^n}+1}$$ and we using that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=0$$ you will get $3$ as the result.